# after opening terminal in 18.04 LTS tpop login required

Tags: boot

I'm pretty new to ubuntu and have the new 18.4 LTS installed which wants me to enter a tpop login after i have'nt used the computer for a while. It wouldn't restart anymore and then crashed. It showed a message which said: before the ppp link was shut down.
I found suggenstions on how to fix that problem but i do not know what to do with the tpop login. My normal password for the computer was rejected.

Philipp! [This is after opening the terminal and the "before ppp link" message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVlk5.jpg)

Comment: Share a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: Sorry. Forgot that but there you go

Comment: `tpop` is the name you've given to the computer when you were installing ubuntu. At the "tpop login" prompt enter your username, and your password next.

Comment: Oh.. :'D okay that does make sense. Thank you so much.